# Writing out elementary subtraction in Latex

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath, underline

I'm hoping to figure out how to write out calculations like this along with the crosses as seen in the image attached. Your help will be greatly appreciated[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I would use an `array` environment, and the `\midrule` command from `booktabs`in the first place. For the ‘crosses’, you have the `cancel` package.

Comment: Do the subscript 10's mean that it is in base 10? Are they really useful? Why do you want the parentheses? Maybe this is a little complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{rrrl}
    \color{blue}4&\color{blue}{12}&\color{blue}{11}\phantom{)_{10}}\\
    (\cancel5&\cancel3&\cancel1)_{10}\\
    (1&9&9)_{10}&-\\ \hline
    (3&3&2)_{10}
  \end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]